# Freezing the 1st two dataColumns in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, datatable, scrollable-table

I have made and dataTable in which i want to fixed the 1st to columns and make the rest scrolable horizontally also the whole table vertically . i had madhe the that with using two datatable but since i have lot of data dynamic i want to use only one datatable.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:tsa/model/rounds/allrounds.dart';
import 'package:tsa/model/rounds/allrounds_list.dart';
import 'package:tsa/notifiers/allroundsNotifier.dart';
import 'package:tsa/pages/loginpage.dart';
import 'package:horizontal_data_table/horizontal_data_table.dart';
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, Key});
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class User {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  User({required this.firstName, required this.lastName});

  static List<User> getUsers() {
    return <User>[
      User(firstName: "Paul", lastName: "Mark"),
      User(firstName: "Paul", lastName: "X"),
      User(firstName: "Owen", lastName: "__"),
      User(firstName: "Paul", lastName: "DNS"),
      User(firstName: "Paul", lastName: "r"),
    ];
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<User> selectedUser = [];
  List<User> users = [];

  var roundlist = <dynamic>[];
  var id = "";
  var fname = "";
  var lname = "";
  var best_5 = 0;
  var best_all = 0;
  var position_after_3 = 0;
  var position_after_5 = 0;
  var position_final = 0;
  var r_1 = 0;
  var r_2 = 0;
  var r_3 = 0;
  var r_4 = 0;
  var r_5 = 0;

  final Map<String, IconData> symbolIconMapping = {
    "wrong": Icons.close,
    "dash": Icons.line_axis,
    "DNS": Icons.dns,
  };

  List<DataRow> rows = [];
  List<DataColumn> columns = [];
  List list_of_data = [];
  List<String> selectedDropdownValue = [
    'Event 1',
    'Event 2',
    'Event 3',
    'Event 4',
    'Event 5',
    'Event 6',
  ];
  String selectedCount = "Event 1";
  getColumns() {
    for (int i = 0; i < dataColumns.length; i++) {
      columns.add(
        // DataColumn(label: dataColumns[i]),
        DataColumn(
          label: SizedBox(
            width: 100, // Adjust the width as needed
            child: Text(
              dataColumns[i],
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              softWrap: true, // Allow text to wrap to the next line
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
  List<dynamic> specialCells = [
    'best_3',
    'best_5',
    'best_all',
    'position_after_3',
    'position_after_5',
    'position_final',
  ];

  List<dynamic> dataCells = [
    'r_1',
    'r_2',
    'r_3',
    'r_4',
    'r_5',
    'r_6',
    'best_3',
    'best_5',
    'best_all',
    'position_after_3',
    'position_after_5',
    'position_final',
  ];
  List<dynamic> dataColumns = [
    "ID",
    "NAME",
    "FIRST",
    "SECOND",
    "THIRD",
    "BEST OF THREE TRIALS",
    "POSITION AFTER THREE TRAILS",
    "FOURTH",
    "FIFTH",
    "BEST OF FIVE TRIALS",
    "POSITION AFTER FIVE TRIALS",
    "SIXTH",
    "BEST OF ALL TRIALS",
    "FINAL POSITION"
  ];
  List value = [];
  TextEditingController dropdownController = TextEditingController();
  // void arrayInit(AllroundsNotifier allroundsNotifier){
  //   var myInt = roundlist;
  //   var i = int.parse(myInt.toString());
  //   list_of_data.add({
  //    "id" : allroundsNotifier.mainAllrounds.data.
  //     "fname" : allroundsNotifier.mainAllrounds.data[i].fname[0];
  //   });
  // }
  late AllRoundsList mainAllrounds;
  bool isCalled = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    users = User.getUsers();
    getColumns();
    selectedUser = List.from(users);
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<AllroundsNotifier> fetchAllData(
      AllroundsNotifier allroundsNotifier) async {
    String URL =
        "https://admin.trackblazerssportsacademy.com/score/score-panel-app";
    Map data = {};
    var body = json.encode(data);
    print(isCalled);
    try {
      if (!isCalled) {
        http.Response response = await http.get(
          Uri.parse(
            URL,
          ),
        );
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
          mainAllrounds = AllRoundsList.fromJson(result);
          allroundsNotifier.setData(mainAllrounds);
          // roundlist = result['data'];
          print(mainAllrounds.data.length);
        }
        rows.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < mainAllrounds.data.length; i++) {
          Map<String, String> concatenatedValues = {};
          for (String cell in dataCells) {
            final cellValue = mainAllrounds.data[i].toJson()[cell];
            concatenatedValues[cell] = '$cellValue';
          }
          rows.add(DataRow(cells: [
            DataCell(
              Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      child: Text(mainAllrounds.data[i].id.toString())),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            DataCell(
              Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Text(
                        "${mainAllrounds.data[i].fname} ${mainAllrounds.data[i].lname}",
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

            ),
            for (String cell in dataCells)
              DataCell(
                  Row(
                    children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        initialValue: concatenatedValues[cell] ?? '',
                        onChanged: (newValue) {},
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(), // Add a border
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), // Add padding
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 5),
                  Expanded(
                    child: DropdownButton<User>(
                      value: selectedUser.isNotEmpty &&
                              i >= 0 &&
                              i < selectedUser.length
                          ? selectedUser[i]
                          : null,
                      onChanged: (newUser) {
                        setState(() {
                          if (i >= 0 && i < selectedUser.length) {
                            selectedUser[i] = newUser!;
                          }
                        });
                      },
                      items: users.map<DropdownMenuItem<User>>((User value) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<User>(
                          value: value,
                          child: Text(value.lastName),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            //       // Column(
            //       //   children: [
            //       //     Text(concatenatedValues[cell] ?? ''),
            //       //     SizedBox(
            //       //
            //       //     )
            //       //   ],
            //       // ),
            //       ),
              )]));
        }
      } else {
        print("already called");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error fetching data: $e");
    }
    return allroundsNotifier;
  }

  void _logout() {
    // You can use Navigator to pop the current page and navigate to the login page.
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
            const LoginPage(), // Replace with your login page widget
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AllroundsNotifier allroundsNotifier =
        Provider.of<AllroundsNotifier>(context, listen: false);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Score Table"),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons
                  .logout), // Use the logout icon or any other icon you prefer
              onPressed: _logout,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: fetchAllData(allroundsNotifier),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4)),
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 4,
                            horizontal: 50), // Adjust the padding as needed
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.orange
                                .shade600, // Set your desired border color here
                            width: 2.0, // Adjust the border width as needed
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                              10.0), // Adjust the border radius for rounded corners
                        ),
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          underline: Container(
                            // To remove the default underline
                            color: Colors.lightBlue.shade50,
                          ),
                          isExpanded: true,
                          elevation: 0,
                          value: selectedCount,
                          items: selectedDropdownValue.map((e) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: e,
                              child: Text(e),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedCount = value.toString();
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 30),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              child: DataTable(
                                  headingRowColor:
                                      MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                                          (states) => Colors.orange),
                                  dataRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                                      (states) => Colors.orange.shade100),
                                  border: TableBorder.all(),
                                  columns: columns,
                                  rows: rows),
                            ),
                          ),
                          //
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }), // You can replace this with your desired content
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried giving wraping the other cells with scroll of horizontal but the app crashes